# Why do I get "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got -" when using COLLECT() in a prepared statement?

Tags: oracle, perl, prepared-statement, aggregate-functions, dbi

I am using this query with the [Perl DBI](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI):

```
SELECT c.change_id
     , COLLECT(t.tag) AS the_tags
  FROM changes   c
  LEFT JOIN tags t ON c.change_id = t.change_id
 WHERE c.project = ?
 GROUP BY c.change_id
```

The DBI uses OCI to prepare this statement, bind the value I pass, and get the results. But Oracle, for some reason, does not like it. The error output is:

```
     ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got - (DBD ERROR: error possibly near <*> indicator at char 41 in '
            SELECT c.change_id
                 , <*>COLLECT(t.tag) AS the_tags
              FROM changes   c
              LEFT JOIN tags t ON c.change_id = t.change_id
             WHERE c.project = :p1
             GROUP BY c.change_id
        '
```

Not very informative. However, I can make this error go away not only by changing the call to `COLLECT()` also by replacing the placeholder with the actual value:

```
     SELECT c.change_id
          , COLLECT(t.tag) AS the_tags
       FROM changes   c
       LEFT JOIN tags t ON c.change_id = t.change_id
      WHERE c.project = 'tryoracle'
      GROUP BY c.change_id
```

That version works perfectly. Why doesn't Oracle like the prepared statement with the `COLLECT()`?

In case it's any help, [here is a trace of the OCI-related calls](https://gist.github.com/theory/5533696) extracted via `ora_verbose = 6` (h/t @bohica).

Comment: theory, A DBD::Oracle ora_verbose=6 trace might be more informative.

Comment: Done, though now it is working. Trying to get it to fail again. Will update that gist…

Comment: There we go. Had to restart the Oracle VM. Whatever.

Comment: This is indeed strange. The parameter is bound as a varchar and given your parameter looks like a string that seems ok - I presume project is a string. The weird bit is the error "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got" which is missing what what was "expected" and what was "got". It is normally something like expected x - got y. Are you by an chance Oracle 10.1.0.0-10.2.0.2 as bug 4381035 might apply.

Comment: Nope, using an [11.2 VirtualBox image](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html).

Comment: I've had the same issue with Oracle XE 11gR2 in SQL Developer directly.I don't think it's related to Perl / OCI, etc, just a plain old Oracle bug. I even got ORA-00600 on some configurations

Comment: @LukasEder Yeah, would be nice if the error message was more informative. The answer I supplied below fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got a solution to this issue, thanks to some digging by a user. The problem was not with the placeholder; why it worked without the placeholder on the VirtualBox image I have no idea. No, the issue was with the `COLLECT()`. Seems that both the values being collected need to be cast to a specific type, *and* the resulting array also needs to be cast to a pre-defined array data type. Just so happens that my code has a custom array type:

```
CREATE TYPE sqitch_array AS varray(1024) OF VARCHAR2(512);
```

So I'm able to get the query to work by casting the `COLLECT()` like so:

```
CAST(COLLECT(CAST(t.tags as VARCHAR2(512))) AS sqitch_array)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in one line? Something along the lines of `CAST(COLLECT(CAST(t.tags as VARCHAR2(512))) AS (varray(1024) OF VARCHAR2(512)))`?

Comment: I mysteriously got ORA-00932 with `select distinct myid, myblobcolumn from mytable`. Removing `distinct` helped.