# Oracle Database 10g: collect, cast for string aggregation

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use `collect` and `cast` for string aggregation, similar to `listagg` in Oracle Database 11 (also, unfortunately, `wm_concat` is not enabled on the database I'm querying). I also have read-only access to this database.

My current query is as follows

```
    SELECT plan.EMPLID,
        plan.STRM TERM,
        CAST(COLLECT(plan.ACAD_PLAN) AS sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll) agg_plans
    FROM SYSADM.PS_OSR_PLAN_TRM plan
    WHERE plan.EMPLID = '999999999'
    GROUP BY plan.EMPLID, plan.STRM
```

This gives me this result:

```
EMPLID      TERM    AGG_PLANS
999999999   1152    SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(VARCHAR(ECON-MN, TXTLCLO-MN))
999999999   1154    SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(VARCHAR(ACCTING-BS, ECON-MN))
```

I believe my logic is correct, but I'm having with trouble with the `cast` statement. I know that `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll` is of type `table of varchar2(1000)`. I would like to remove `SYS.DBMS_DEBUG_VC2COLL(VARCHAR(` from each row and simply list the results.

Is there a way to join together the resulting collection into a string? This stack overflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16407560/why-do-i-get-ora-00932-inconsistent-datatypes-expected-got-when-using-co) has something similar to what I'm looking for... however, again, I have readonly access to this database. I'd also like to try to keep it one select statement.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: I am not opposed to a solution that uses `xmlagg`.

Comment: Have you tried using `XMLAGG()`?

Comment: Yea, I wasn't getting the same results however. Do you have any links/examples you can point me toward?

Comment: See [here for a list of string aggregation techniques](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php). You can use `COLLECT()` but you need to write a function to convert the tabled results to a string.

Comment: And see this question for an answer using `XMLAGG()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190598/aggregate-string-connection-in-oracle-10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `XMLAGG()` as follows:

```
SELECT plan.emplid, plan.strm AS term
     , RTRIM( XMLAGG( XMLELEMENT(e, plan.acad_plan || ',') ORDER BY plan.acad_plan ).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',' ) AS agg_plans
  FROM sysadm.ps_osr_plan_trm plan
 WHERE plan.emplid = '999999999'
 GROUP BY plan.emplid, plan.strm;
```

Note that the first parameter to `XMLELEMENT()` can be anything, it is simply the XML tag in which the value of `plan.acad_plan || ','` will be wrapped, and ultimately it will be discarded.

Comment: Yes. I just discovered this way of doing it. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: The only caveat is that it may not work if the resulting aggregated string is > 4000 bytes.

Comment: Do you know why there is a 4000 byte limit?

Comment: The limit isn't on `XMLAGG()` but using `RTRIM()` with the results of `XMLAGG()`. [See here for more info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299843/xmlagg-with-rtrim-issue) and a solution.